# Visual Studio add-in to quickly test a code snippet

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

One thing I really love about languages such as Python is that if you have a piece of code you'd like to try out, you can just open the interactive shell and do it in seconds.

Is there a Visual Studio add-in that does the same for C#?

Basically what I'm looking for is something that opens up a window or tab with a text editor (preferably with code completion, because VS does it so nicely) and a button that runs the code and displays the output. Extra points for convenience features such as displaying complex output in a user-friendly way (think Firebug's `console.log`), automatically referencing all the assemblies the current project references, etc.

I tried googling for a while, but either I fail at coming up with good keywords, or no-one has made an add-in like this. If there really is none, I'm considering making one myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about an add-in for VS but anytime I want to try something quickly (and don't want to fire up VS and create a console app) I use [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/). It gets the job done as far as quickly testing methods and what not. I usually use it for things like testing a regex or trying out random datetime formatters. You can add references to other assemblies and it does provide some degree of intellisense.

Comment: This looks very promising. I might even be able to semi-integrate this into VS by creating a macro that launches it with some parameters for references etc, if it supports it. Hold on while I give it a spin.

Comment: I guess this is the closest I can get without writing a whole VS add-in. Even though it's not exactly what I was looking for, it's pretty close, and I can always write that macro I thought about. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) will execute C# snippets as well as LINQ.  Nice except that autocompletion is not included in the free version.  Of course you can write statements in VS with autocompletion, then copy/paste them into Linqpad.

Answer (score 1):

I have a `test.vcproj` project sitting around with a `test.cpp` file which I paste code into. It's the best I could come up with.

Comment: same here. Another method, somewhat quicker but less versatile is a commandline compile; I have a few bat files like 'compile_and_run.bat' taking a single file as argument.